# Flask sessions and static files

Tags: session, flask, flask-session

I use a custom `SessionInterface` implementation that interacts with a DynamoDB database. It looks like the session is loaded for every request including requests for static files.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean a new session is created for every request?

Comment: No, a session is loaded (open_session call) for every request which is overkill if done for static files too.

Comment: The session should not be loaded for static files. Especially in prod, it won't happen since they will be served by Apache/nginx. I'm trying to get the same behavior on dev.